# How to truncate a decimal to 2 places?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a value 100.0000. I need truncate it to only two decimal places like 100.00  I need to do it when it have 00's in 3rd and 4 places. How to do it??

Comment: We need more info. What do you mean when you say you have a value that is `100.0000`, is that a `string`? Because, if it's a `double` then they automatically truncate the ending zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle financial values, you must use `decimal`.
To another type of properties, you can use `double`

Based on my experience, you don't want to truncate because if you truncate, you'll lose part of the value. I think you want to round. In c#, you can round using `Math.Ceiling()`

```
double result = Math.Ceiling(value);
```

But, if you still want to truncate the value to two decimal places, you can do it two ways, using, for example, string interpolation:

if you want formated string:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{value:N2}");
```

if you don't need formated string:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{value:F2}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy: all you have to do is use the format specifier as an argument to the ToString() method. In this case it would be "F2":

```
double value = 100.0000;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F2"));
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Answer (score 0):

decimal dec = 100.000;

```
dec .ToString ("#.##"); // returns "" when decimalVar == 0
```

and if you want to keep it as decimal not string use

```
dec = Math.Round( dec ,  2 , MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

for more details follow this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Decimal_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_System_MidpointRounding_